# Add Swipe Touch listener on a relative layout with Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to add a swip Touch Listener (swip left, right, ...) on an activity that use a recycler view inside it.it worked for me but in case of not using a recycler view inside, but when I add recycler view and set information of a list,the swip touch listener does not even work ! any help please ? and Thanks in advance !

Here is my code that I tried :

**MenuActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //......here 1

    listView=findViewById(R.id.list_codes);
    listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MenuActivity.this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
    getCodes();
    Global.currentCode=this.code_1;
    processData(Global.currentCode);
    //here 2
    relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_activity_menu);
    relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MenuActivity.this) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MenuActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MenuActivity.this,SnowtamDecodeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

**OnSwipTouchListener.java**

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
}
```

**activity_menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_activity_menu"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MenuActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/blueCustom"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<!--<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_activity_aerodrome_name_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Hello Mohammed Kasmi"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>-->

<!--<include layout="@layout/content_menu" />-->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_codes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    />
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `RecyclerView` you would want to use an [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper) which you then attach to the `RecyclerView` itself.

Like this:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback =
        new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                // TODO do something when swiped
            }
        };

ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

This example shows the right swipe via `ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT` but there are other options.